# pass array of objects to array

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, lodash

I’ve the following object which needs to get and array of values

```
 const myVal: QuickPickItem[] = [data.result.eventDefinitions.data]
```

The array should get items like [ “a1”,”a2”,”a3”]

The  `data.result.eventDefinitions.data` is array of objects,

```
data.result.eventDefinitions.data = 
{
name:”aaaa”
desc:”test”

},
{
name:”bbbb”
desc:”test2”

}
```

How should I pass the values of names to `myVal` to be an array like

`[ “aaaa”,bbbb”]` , should I use lodash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.result.eventDefinitions.data.map(el => el.name)`

Answer (score 2):

That can be done with the native array.map()

Just pass the items to map than have it return the value of name and you will end up with the array you specified.

```
let newArray = data.result.eventDefinitions.data.map(item => item.name)
```